# Image refuses to overlay another image within div

Tags: html, css, django, image, overlay

I cannot seem to get this icon to fit within this div. I have a div containing the first image (as well as the second icon-image). Parent div has a transparent background-overlay. Then, the image. Now, I'm trying to get the icon to overlay but it seems to be acting according to inline-block properties.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
<div class="slide">
  <div class="imageoverlay">
    <img class="slide-img z-depth-5" src="{% static 'projectweekapp/images/7.jpg' %}" alt="">
    <img class="footer-icon" src="{% static 'projectweekapp/images/heart_white.png' %}" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

.slide{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.imageoverlay{
 min-width: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 background: linear-gradient(to top,
    rgba(0,0,0, .7) 15%,
    rgba(255,255,255, 0) 70%
 );
}

.slide-img{
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.footer-icon{
  max-width: 20px !important;
  max-height: 20px !important;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
.slide{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}

.imageoverlay{
 min-width: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 background: linear-gradient(to top,
    rgba(0,0,0, .7) 15%,
    rgba(255,255,255, 0) 70%
 );
}

.slide-img{
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.footer-icon{
  max-width: 20px !important;
  max-height: 20px !important;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Add `position: relative` to `.slide` and `bottom: 0` to `.footer-icon`.

Comment: Awesome! Much love.